# show hide content depending if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, show-hide

I'm pretty new to jquery so I'm proud of myself for what I've figured out so far. What I'm trying to do is show/hide a list of options depending on the approprate check box status. Eveything is working just fine but I can't figure out how to check to see if a check box is checked on load I know I should be able to use `is.checked` right now I have this javascript

```
    $('.wpbook_hidden').css({
    'display': 'none'
});
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    var option = 'wpbook_option_' + $(this).attr('id');
    if ($('.' + option).css('display') == 'none') {
        $('.' + option).fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('.' + option).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Which fades in and out a class depending on the status of the checkbox.  This is my html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="set_1" checked> click to show text1
<p class = "wpbook_hidden wpbook_option_set_1"> This is option one</p>
<p class = "wpbook_hidden wpbook_option_set_1"> This is another option one</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="set_2"> click to show text1
<p class = "wpbook_hidden wpbook_option_set_2"> This is option two</p>
```

The two problems I have are that the content with the `.wpbook_hidden` class is always hidden and if the checkbox is checked on load the content should load.

If someone could figure out how to check the status of the box on load that would be much appriciated feel free to play with this jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MH8e4/3/

Comment: I'm not sure what fadeIn() does exactly, but I don't think it sets the display to block, so the content probably does not show up.

Comment: fadeIn just tells the content to fade in when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `:checked` as a selector. like this,

```
alert($(':checkbox:checked').attr('id'));
```

## [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MH8e4/4/)

or if you want to check the state of a particular checkbox, it would be something like this

```
alert($('#set_1')[0].checked);
```

## [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MH8e4/5/)

---

for the comment below, I have edited your code and now looks like this.

```
$('.wpbook_hidden').hide();

$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    changeCheck(this);
});

$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){ // on page load, get the checked checkbox.
    changeCheck(this); // apply function same as what is in .change()
});

function changeCheck(x) {
    var option = 'wpbook_option_' + $(x).attr('id');
    if ($('.' + option).is(':visible')) { // I'm not sure about my if here.
        $('.' + option).fadeOut();        // if necessary try exchanging the fadeOut() and fadeIn()
    }
    else {
        $('.' + option).fadeIn();
    }
}
```

### #[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MH8e4/6/)

Comment: great, that tells me which boxes are checked but how would I show the content of `wpbook_option_set_1` on load for example sense it's checked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(fun....
```

Answer (score 0):

to checkout if a checkbox is checked you can use the following code :

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  if ( $(this).checked == true ){
     //your code here
   }

});
```

Comment: it's `this.checked` and not `$(this).checked`. if you use `$(this)`, it would be `$(this).attr('checked')` ;)