# How to hide and show item if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am trying to hide and show an area based on whether a checkbox is checked. I've tried some options but either the area is visible all of the time or it is hidden all of the time.

**JavaScript :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mgift = $('#chkbxMGift input[type=checkbox]');     
    MshowHide();    

    mgift.change(function () {
        MshowHide();
    });
});


function MshowHide() {
    var mgift = $('#chkbxMGift input[type=checkbox]');
    var shcompany = $('#shcompany');

    if (mgift.checked) {
        shcompany.show();
    } else {       
        shcompany.hide();        
    }
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<li>
    <div class="info">                 
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxMGift" runat="server" Text="A matching gift will be made" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
    </div>
</li>

<li id="shcompany">    
    <div class="info">               
        <label for="txtCompanyName">Company Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCompanyName" CssClass="narrow" />   
    </div>
    <div class="info">  
        <label for="txtCompanyPhone">Company Phone Number</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCompanyPhone" CssClass="narrow"  />       
    </div>
</li>
```

How can I make this work correctly?

Comment: is your html incomplete? cant see checkbox?

Comment: you need to take this function call off MshowHide(); maybe

Comment: @AshReva the checkbox right below the li

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide show based on selected Radio Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300638/hide-show-based-on-selected-radio-button)

Comment: @CBroe well I am using a checkbox now and it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Checkbox or Radiobutton does not make much of a difference. And one would hope (at least I do), that you _learn_ something from the answers you are getting here – but you still come along with “it does not work” …

Comment: @CBroe I used what I learnt from the question before to build on what I did just now along with google. I just seem to be stomped

Comment: @Robertpurpose have a look at my answer,it solves ur issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#chkbxMGift').click(function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         if ($this.is(':checked')) {
             $('#shcompany').hide();
         } else {
             $('#shcompany').show();
         }
     });
 });
```

Hope it solves your issue

Comment: But you don't check the initial status.

Comment: i just modified the code in the question to make the hide and show work :)

Comment: if u want to remove that its fine.I mean it serves the purpose, just my way of writing $(this)

Answer (score 4):

Your selector is wrong.

```
var mgift = $('#chkbxMGift input[type=checkbox]');
```

This means you select the childnode `input` from parent `#chkbxMGift`.

I believe this is the selector you need:

```
var mgift = $('input#chkbxMGift[type=checkbox]');
```

And here are some improvements on your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mgift = $('input#chkbxMGift[type=checkbox]'); 
    var shcompany = $('#shcompany');
    // check for default status (when checked, show the shcompany)
    if (mgift.attr('checked') !== undefined){
        shcompany.show();
    } else {
        shcompany.hide();
    }

    // then simply toggle the shcompany on every change
    mgift.change(function(){
        shcompany.toggle();
    });
});
```

jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is really useful and added in version 1.0, so you should be able to just go with that.

Here's a proof of concept in a jsFiddle, with only the bare minimum:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y39Bu/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is stolen from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860629/show-hide-content-depending-if-a-checkbox-is-checked?rq=1) answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/MH8e4/4/

```
$('.wpbook_hidden').css({
'display': 'none'
});

alert($(':checkbox:checked').attr('id'))
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    var option = 'wpbook_option_' + $(this).attr('id');
    if ($('.' + option).css('display') == 'none') {
        $('.' + option).fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('.' + option).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

search for similar questions before you ask yours. Please give the original author the credit if this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the CSS directly? Such as

```
document.getElementById("shcompany").style.display="none";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("shcompany").style.visibility="hidden";
```

(or "visible")

Comment: Well Thats what I did when I orginally did the function with a radiobutton list then i updated it to the show hide functions and a checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Why use JQuery when a simple CSS property change can do the trick?

Just change the div's class or modify it's style:

If you want it to **take up space even when hidden** use `visibility:hidden` (respectively `visibility:visible`)

if you want it **NOT** to take space when hidden use css `display:none` (respectively `display:block`)